# VB.NET Combobox AutoCompleteMode = Append, AutoCompleteSource = ListItems does not work when the DropDown is open

Tags: vb.net, combobox, append, dropdown

Here is my Combobox settings,

AutoCompleteMode = Append
 AutoCompleteSource = ListItems

In **SelectionChangeCommitted** event handler i am loading the some other combos based on the **SelectedIndex**.

**When the DropDown is NOT OPEN**(in this case user may select the dropdown by pressing TAB), if the user types "abc", an item starting with "acb" will get selected and the selection is retained after the user press TAB again to go to the next control. In this scenario it works as expected.

**But when the DropDown is OPEN**(in this case the user clicks manually on the combobox) and types some letters, for example "abc", an item starting with text "abc" will get highlighted(this is normal). But the problem occurs when the user press TAB at this stage. Now the combobox will revert to someother value and the highlighted item will not get selected. So it appears like the "APPEND" mode is not working when the dropdown is open, it works more like "SUGGEST" in this case.

I read numerous posts about this, however i could not find any solution to this issue. Please note that i don't want to close the dropdown to make it work. I want the dropdown to be open if the user clicks on the combo.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.